# Save function returning false

Tags: java, swt, ole, savefiledialog

I am using the SWT integration of Office to work with office document, my problem is when saving the changes of the file. I am using this code :

```
FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(getShell(), SWT.SAVE);
        String path = dialog.open();
        if (path != null) {
          if (clientSite.save(new File(path), false)) {
            System.out.println("Saved to file successfully.");
          } else {
            System.err.println("Failed to save to file");
          }
        }
      }
```

The problem is that the save function is returning false no matter what file do I provide. this means file is not saved.
Can any one assist.
Kind regards

Comment: Please add language tag to make it easier for people to help you

Comment: What is `clientSite`?

Comment: I am instanciating the class OleClientSite

Comment: OleClientSite oleClientSite = new OleClientSite(oleFrame, SWT.NONE,
    "Word.Application");

Comment: Language tag is already made "Java"

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
clientSite.save(new File(path), true)
```

For some reason you need to that the magical flag to `true` for the old Offices formats.